# How to style in Angular JS / Ionic based upon bind expression?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, ionic-framework

I cannot seem to find out how to style based on an expression within Angular JS. Essentially I call an API that has a **status_option** this returns either Pending, In Progress or Complete. I would like it so that the style of the status color is automatically changed when this is done so within the expression.

Note  the expression updates fine when this is changed within the API.

I have attempted to use **ng-style** along with **ng-class** to update this however cannot seem to have much luck.

Any ideas how to update the color would be great.

```
<div class="card" ng-repeat="delivery in allocations.allocation_deliveries">
    <div class="item item-divider">
        <i class="ion-information-circled"></i>Deliveries
    </div>

<div class="detail-status">
    {{delivery.status_option}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
<div class="detail-status" ng-class="delivery.status_option">
    {{delivery.status_option}}
</div>
```

For `delivery.status_option === "Pending"`, that should result in:

```
<div class="detail-status Pending">
    Pending
</div>
```

Then, assign the colours you want to the proper css classes:

```
detail-status.Pending { color: red }
detail-status.InProgress { color: yellow }
detail-status.Complete { color: green }
```